# Bind9 refuses key from nsupdate

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dynamic-dns, ddns, nsupdate

I have a Bind9 DNS server running (and working!). All the zones were managed manually. I now want to change a zone to be updated automatically. After setting things up i tried nsupdate but it fails with "refused". I have no idea why that is the case.

Configuration: rndc.key is included in named.conf

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
```

i also added allow update statement to my named.conf.local AND made sure that the zone file is in `/var/lib/bind`

```
root@ns1:/etc/bind# cat named.conf.local
zone "somedomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.somedomain.com";
        #update-policy {grant "rndc.key" zonesub ANY;} ;
        allow-update { key rndc.key;};
        allow-transfer { some IP; };
};
```

The key exists:

```
root@ns1:/etc/bind# cat rndc.key
key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "<secret>";
};
```

But when i try to update vie nsupdate from localhost it refuses it.

```
root@ns1:/etc/bind# nsupdate
> server localhost
> key rndc-key <secret>
> zone somedomain.com
> update add test.somedomain.com. 600 IN A someIP
> send
update failed: REFUSED
```

syslog also didnt help me much

```
May 24 22:37:20 ns1 named[30755]: client @0x7f1f8c0e3840 127.0.0.1#27482/key rndc-key: signer "rndc-key" denied
May 24 22:37:20 ns1 named[30755]: client @0x7f1f8c0e3840 127.0.0.1#27482/key rndc-key: update 'somedomain.com/IN' denied
May 24 22:38:09 ns1 named[30755]: resolver priming query complete
May 24 22:38:38 ns1 named[30755]: resolver priming query complete
```

i copy and pasted the key so there should be no typo. These are all original terminal outputs, just domains and IPs changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the key in the `allow-update` statement is `rndc.key`, but the name of the key that you show and that you use on the client side is `rndc-key`?

Does `rndc.key` (as in the name of a key, not the file) even exist? If not, does the configuration even load cleanly? Regardless which, the key name as well as the secret must match, so this would appear to be the problem.

Sidenote, why repurpose the key that is intended for use with `rndc` for other purposes? Just create a new key for the intended purpose (see `tsig-keygen`) and leave the `rndc` key alone!
(I would also question the use of MD5 in this day and age. I suppose in HMAC use it is not utterly broken, but why even go there?)

Comment: I did that and it worked. I dont know why i didnt created a new key to beginn with...